# Unix loops and conditions (Modulo operator, test if in alphabet)

Tags: loops, unix, modulo

I was after some help on a simple enough problem ;), but as I am new to Unix, I am running into problems. What I have is a log file (comma deliminator) made up of time stamps and user id's.

```
2014 03 06 11:21:30:641,test_ess20 and sleep(4)
2014 03 06 11:21:30:701,test_ess20
2014 03 06 11:21:30:767,test_ess20 or (sleep(4)+1) limit 1 --
2014 03 06 11:21:30:864,test_ess20
2014 03 06 11:21:31:076,S7989676
2014 03 06 11:21:30:915,test_ess20
2014 03 06 11:21:30:976,test_ess20'; waitfor delay '0:0:4' --
2014 03 06 11:21:31:076,test_ess20"; waitfor delay '0:0:4' --
```

What I would like to do is test each user id to make sure it is valid. This means that it begins with a single letter of the alphabet and is followed by a string of number (variable in length). Also, this variable number and the number '8' must produce a modulo of 4. If this is true, nothing happens ie it is a valid user. If not, I would like to append ##ERROR to the end of line in the log file.

I hope you guys can follow and appreciate the assistance

PS: In the sample data above there is only x1 valid user.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  `bash`?  Do you have programming experience in any language?

Comment: Am using bash but am used to C# VBA

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want to do it. If you want to bash script, python, pearl, awk. If I were you, I will either use python/perl and regular expression.

Comment: Yeah, doing it in bash but have just stumbled on to regular expression. Will try and go that way... Below is where I got to

Comment: for i in $(cat myTemp.txt | awk -F',' '{print $2}'); do char1=`echo $i | cut -c1`; str=`echo $i | cut -c2-`; echo $str " " $char1; done